# To remove an unmatched string from a imported CSV file using pandas and fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzywuzzy

Hi I am working on removing an unmatched string from an imported CSV file using pandas and fuzzywuzzy

The inputs taken from the CSV File are as follows

```
ID,Title
1,The One and Only Ivan (Korean Edition)
1,The One and Only Ivan CD
1,The One and Only Ivan
1,The One And Only Ivan (Turtleback School & Library Binding Edition)
1,The One and Only Ivan
1,The One and Only Ivan: A Harper Classic
1,The One and Only Ivan Full-Color Collector's Edition
1,The One And Only Ivan
1,The One and Only Ivan
1,One and Only Ivan
1,Paris Match (A Stone Barrington Novel)
1,The One and Only Ivan
2,FuzzyWuzzy Ratio
2,FuzzyWuzzy PartialRatio
2,No Trespassing
2,FuzzyWuzzy TokenSortRatio
2,FuzzyWuzzy TokenSetRatio
2,FuzzyWuzzy WRatio
3, Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone
3, Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets
3, Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban
3, Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire
3,Gun Island: A Novel
3, Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix
3, Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince
3, Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows
```

The above fields are input from the csv file.

> They need to be grouped by their ID and should be updated using fuzzywuzzy.

The desired output is :

```
1,The One and Only Ivan (Korean Edition),Match
1,The One and Only Ivan C,Match
1,The One and Only Ivan,Match
1,The One And Only Ivan (Turtleback School & Library Binding Edition),Match
1,The One and Only Ivan,Match
1,The One and Only Ivan: A Harper Classic,Match
1,The One and Only Ivan Full-Color Collector's Edition,Match
1,The One And Only Ivan,Match
1,The One and Only Ivan,Match
1,One and Only Ivan,Match
1,Paris Match (A Stone Barrington Novel),UnMatched
1,The One and Only Ivan,Match
2,FuzzyWuzzy Ratio,Match
2,FuzzyWuzzy PartialRatio,Match
2,No Trespassing,UnMatched
2,FuzzyWuzzy TokenSortRatio,Match
2,FuzzyWuzzy TokenSetRatio,Match
2,FuzzyWuzzy WRatio,Match
3, Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone,Match
3, Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets,Match
3, Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban,Match
3, Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire,Match
3,Gun Island: A Novel,UnMatched
3, Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix,Match
3, Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince,Match
3, Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows,Match
```